# Как отправить изображение чтобы оно открылось в браузере, а не скачивалось?

Tags: golang

Пытался просто отправить `<img src=....>`
даже с content-type html запускается скачивание.

Comment: `content-type` должен быть `text/html`

Answer (score 0):

`Content-type` должен быть `text/html`, а не `html`. Вот рабочий пример,

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    var (
        mux = gin.Default()
        err error
    )

    mux.GET("/img", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(200)
        c.Writer.WriteString(`<img src="/ring.png">`)
    })

    mux.GET("/ring.png", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.File("./ring.png")
    })

    if err = mux.Run(":8000"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Дерево проекта:

```
main.go
ring.png
```